# Return few functions back

Tags: python-3.x, function, back

I wanted to know if there is a way to go back 2 functions back:

```
def a():
    b()
    print(2)  # I do not want to get here

def b():
    print(1)
    return  # Now I want to go back to main

def main():
    a()
```

I hope you understand what I want because I know that in assembly you can go few functions back because it has something to do with the stack pointer

Comment: Python does not have something like a `goto`, so you'll have to re-organize your functions instead. How about letting `main` call `b()` after returning from `a()`?

Comment: Because In my real code I need to run a() and only if something happens in b() (an if statement) I need to get back to main()